# SO_REUSEADDR option affects fragmentation?

Tags: sockets

I've faced with an interesting behavior of UDP socket with SO_REUSEADDR option set...

If I send 1472 bytes over IP/UDP I get it all in one frame - that' expected...

BUT for 1473 fragmentation differs with/without that option. Does anyone has a clue why that occurs (I'm using Debian 2.6.32-5-amd64)?

***SO_REUSEADDR Enabled:***

**FRAME#1**

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 173.59.3.22 (173.59.3.22), Dst: 173.70.1.5 (173.70.1.5)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: **1476**
    Identification: 0x214d (8525)
    Flags: 0x01 (More Fragments)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
        ..1. .... = More fragments: Set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0xd53f [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 173.59.3.22 (173.59.3.22)
    Destination: 173.70.1.5 (173.70.1.5)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
User Datagram Protocol (**8** bytes)
    Source port: icl-twobase1 (25000)
    Destination port: 5000 (5000)
    Length: **1481**
    Checksum: 0x3cac [unchecked, not all data available]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
Data (**1448** bytes)
```

**FRAME#2**

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 173.59.3.22 (173.59.3.22), Dst: 173.70.1.5 (173.70.1.5)br/>
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: **45**
    Identification: 0x214d (8525)
    Flags: 0x00
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 1456
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0xfa20 [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 173.59.3.22 (173.59.3.22)
    Destination: 173.70.1.5 (173.70.1.5)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Data (**25** bytes)
```

***SO_REUSEADDR Disabled:***

**FRAME#1**

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 173.59.3.22 (173.59.3.22), Dst: 173.70.1.5 (173.70.1.5)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: **1500**
    Identification: 0x214a (8522)
    Flags: 0x01 (More Fragments)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
        ..1. .... = More fragments: Set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0xd52a [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 173.59.3.22 (173.59.3.22)
    Destination: 173.70.1.5 (173.70.1.5)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]

User Datagram Protocol (**8** bytes)
    Source port: icl-twobase1 (25000)
    Destination port: 5000 (5000)
    Length: **1481**
    Checksum: 0x3cac [unchecked, not all data available]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
Data (**1472** bytes)
```

**FRAME#2**

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 173.59.3.22 (173.59.3.22), Dst: 173.70.1.5 (173.70.1.5)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: **21**
    Identification: 0x214a (8522)
    Flags: 0x00
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 1480
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0xfa38 [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 173.59.3.22 (173.59.3.22)
    Destination: 173.70.1.5 (173.70.1.5)
    [Source GeoIP: Unknown]
    [Destination GeoIP: Unknown]
Data (**1** byte)
```

Comment: Good question. 1. What are the source and destination ports with `SO_REUSEADDR` enabled vs. disabled? Your trace doesn't seem to contain them. 2. Was this trace taken near the sender or near the receiver? If it was taken near the receiver then the fragment arrangement might have changed en route (though that's not really supposed to happen — routers are not supposed to reassemble).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The trace was collected on the sending machine. Src Port is 25000 and Dst port is 5000. No such Src port opened according to netstat output

Comment: I can't think of any reason for the different fragmentation. Hopefully someone else will know the answer. Of course, both ways of fragmenting are valid, so I expect it's not a problem either way.

Comment: That was a surprise while my app IP fragmentation functionality testing, MTU is less than 1500 on the next hop, and with the option set I failed to test that until found the reason. Just wondering why that happens.

However, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **NO** - **SO_REUSEADDR doesn't affect fragmentation**...

The clue is **MTU Discovery** and **Don't Fragment Flag** in IP Header. 
In case of sending of 1472 bytes with MTU Discovery = ON:
1500 bytes sent with Don't Frag Flag ON => I get ICMP:

Internet Control Message Protocol
    Type: 3 (Destination unreachable)
    **Code: 4 (Fragmentation needed)**

    Checksum: 0x90db [correct]
    **MTU of next hop: 1480**

After that the sender does fragmentation for all packets to fit 1480 MTU while route\arp cache info is kept for that receiver (5 min for route and 30 sec for arp - defaults configured on my system).

That's why I saw unexpected for me fragmentation of 1473 bytes (1456 + 25 bytes in two frames) (SO_REUSEADDR was ON in that experiment)...

Next time I tried sending the same 1473 bytes (SO_REUSEADDR was OFF) route\arp cache freed the info about the receiver and I saw that different confusing fragmentation (1480 + 1 bytes in two frames).

Sorry for everyone for the confusion...
However that was pretty cognitive for me to dig into such behavior and clarify things I observed. No miracles here.